# How can I do this without the cases?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, cases

How can I do this without the cases?

```
$\begin{cases} 
 \dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}=2x=\dfrac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial y} \\ 
 \dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}=-2y=- \dfrac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial x} 
 \end{cases} 
 \forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$
```

Comment: `aligned` instead of `cases`? With a `&` to start the rows. [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: For your information, if you type 4 spaces before a line, it will be shown as `code`.

Comment: do you wanna avoid the brace or just do it in another way with brace?

Comment: wanna avoid the brace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the typeset result, I'd say you're looking not for `cases` or `aligned`, but `alignedat` (or its standalone version, `alignat`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\noindent Standalone:
\begin{alignat*}{99}
    \dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}&{}={}& 2&x={}&  &\dfrac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial y} \\ 
    \dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}&{}={}&-2&y={}& -&\dfrac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial x} 
\end{alignat*}
Embedded:
\begin{align*}
  \begin{alignedat}{99}
    \dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}&{}={}& 2&x={}&  &\dfrac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial y} \\ 
    \dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}&{}={}&-2&y={}& -&\dfrac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial x} 
  \end{alignedat}
  &&
  \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The `{99}` argument is there to satisfy an obtuse requirement of the environment: it specifies the maximum number of columns.  I generally don't care to count, so I just make it absurdly large.

[image]

It's also possible to have the `2x` centered, as tohecz requests, but this entails a small amount of hackery.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\noindent Default
\begin{align*}
  \begin{alignedat}{99}
    \dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}&{}={}& 2&x={}&  &\dfrac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial y} \\ 
    \dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}&{}={}&-2&y={}& -&\dfrac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial x} 
  \end{alignedat}
  &&
  \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}
$2x$ centered:
\begin{align*}
  \begin{alignedat}{99}
    \dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}&{}={}&\omit\hfil$2x$\hfil&{}={}&  &\dfrac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial y} \\ 
    \dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}&{}={}& -2y &{}={}& -&\dfrac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial x} 
  \end{alignedat}
  &&
  \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Namely, you have to remove the "template" from the column containing `2x` and replace it with the necessary glue (not forgetting the `$ $`, because those are normally included in the template).  This entails a slightly different arrangement of columns than before, since now we want to keep the entire monomial together.

[image]

Comment: The extra space in fron of `2x` seems to be disturbing to me. If you really want all the `=` aligned, you might consider centering `2x` there ;)

Comment: @tohecz: I like to have the variables aligned, but that could just be my linear algebra lectures talking.

Comment: I don't like it because it looks like that a `-` is missing in the first line :-/

Comment: @tohecz: How do you like my new example?

Comment: +1, just there's still the same problem in front of `dv/dy` ;)

Comment: @tohecz: No, that one stays :) Centered `2x` only works visually because it's the center equation.

Comment: +1 for the `{99}` idea.  I've gone cross-eyed counting columns in the `alignat` environment.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I learned that somewhere on here, I think.  At least, someone said that it's a *maximum*, not an *exact* count.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I'm not enthusiast at all about the `{99}`. Use the *right* number.

Comment: @egreg: I agree, except that if it mattered that the number were correct, then it would be an exact count rather than a maximum.  The fact that I can get away with this points to a flaw in the design (say, the default should be up to n columns requires no count, and for more you specify them exactly as an optional argument).  I don't feel bad "redefining" `alignat` to adhere to this more sensible standard.

Comment: @egreg: I agree with you in principle too.  But at least when drafting I might start with the 99 then count once I have proof of concept.

Answer (score 7):

`amsmath` provides a bunch of environments for alignments; in this case you're probably looking for `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned} 
& \dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}=2x=\dfrac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial y} \\ 
& \dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}=-2y=- \dfrac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial x} 
\end{aligned}
\quad
\forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd never use it inline, though.

Comment: Don't forget `\!` before `aligned`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean literally not using "cases" as in this?

```
$
   \begin{array}{l}
     \dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}=2x=\dfrac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial y} \\ 
     \dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}=-2y=- \dfrac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial x} 
   \end{array}
   \forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2
$
```

Or am I not understanding the question?  [I edited to remove the brace]