# Centering equations within alignat command

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, align

I want to centre the formula inside the equals. So far I have

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}    
v_2(16)&=\frac{2}{5}[v_3(32)+v_3(8)] &&= 0, \\
v_2(4)&=\frac{2}{5}[v_3(8)+v_3(2)] &&= 1.20,\\   
v_2(1)&=\frac{2}{5}[v_3(2)+v_3(0.50)] &&= 3.
\end{alignat*}
```

Basically I have

```
 A =BBB = CC

 A =B   = CCCC
```

but I want

```
 A = BBB = CC

 A =  B  =CCCC
```

Comment: Hi Joshua, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I marked up your code using `{}`; I also removed the thanks, which is just our policy here- we like to say thanks by upvoting :) It helps keep the site more like a Q&A site- welcome! :)

Comment: Do the answers to the following question help you? [Align two inequalities](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4273)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To have each of the three "columns" centered, you could use the `array` environment. Note (i) the specification of the `=` column dividers in the header of the array environment, to ensure math-appropriate spacing, and (ii) the reset of the `\arraystretch` parameter to get a look that's appropriate for a group of displayed equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33} % default value: 1.0
\[
\begin{array}{c @{{}={}} c @{{}={}} c}
v_2(16) & \frac{2}{5}[v_3(32)+v_3(8)]    & 0, \\
v_2(4)  & \frac{2}{5}[v_3(8) +v_3(2)]    & 1.20,\\   
v_2(1 ) & \frac{2}{5}[v_3(2) +v_3(0.50)] & 3.
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to typeset the left-most column flush-right against the first `=` sign and the right-most column flush-left against the second `=` sign, you could set `{r @{{}={}} c @{{}={}} l}` as the array header specification.

---

Rather than center-set the middle portions of the equations, I would actually recommend maintaining the `alignat*` environment while adding a further alignment point, at the `+` sign. I'd also use `\tfrac` rather than `frac`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}    
v_2(16)&=\tfrac{2}{5}[v_3(32) &&+v_3(8)]    &&= 0, \\
v_2(4) &=\tfrac{2}{5}[v_3(8)  &&+v_3(2)]    &&= 1.20,\\   
v_2(1) &=\tfrac{2}{5}[v_3(2)  &&+v_3(0.50)] &&= 3.
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

This is similar to a problem I addressed in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100337/how-can-i-do-this-without-the-cases/100345#100345).  You can do this by inserting some "rubber lengths", i.e. stretchable space, if you override the alignment defaults of the `alignat` environment.  In your case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\centermathcell[1]{\omit\hfil$\displaystyle#1$\hfil\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  v_2(16) &={}& \centermathcell{\frac{2}{5}[v_3(32)+v_3(8)]}   &= 0, \\
  v_2(4)  &={}& \centermathcell{\frac{2}{5}[v_3(8)+v_3(2)]}    &= 1.20,\\
  v_2(1)  &={}& \centermathcell{\frac{2}{5}[v_3(2)+v_3(0.50)]} &= 3.
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The macro `\centermathcell` (which is descriptively named but which you can of course shorten) uses `\omit` to remove the default alignment in the current cell, and replaces it with centering. (The `\ignorespaces` is there to prevent whitespace after `\centermathcell` from creating spurious gaps in the output.)  I've reorganized the columns a bit so that the material which must be centered entirely occupies its own column.

This has the advantage over using the `array` environment that the behavior of `alignat` is otherwise preserved, and is less verbose than the `\fakewidth` idea.  It has the disadvantage of going outside the LaTeX typesetting structures and coding paradigm, since `\omit` is a TeX primitive and you are "not supposed to know" how `alignat` is implemented (in this case, as an `\halign` of some sort).

Answer (score 4):

If you type

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newlength\wantedwidth
\newcommand{\fakewidth}[2]{%
  \settowidth{\wantedwidth}{\ensuremath{#2}}%
  \makebox[\wantedwidth]{\ensuremath{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}    
  v_2(16)&=\fakewidth{\frac{2}{5}[v_3(32)+v_3(8)]}
                    {\frac{2}{5}[v_3(2)+v_3(0.50)]}
                    &&= \fakewidth{0,}{1.20} \\
  v_2(4)&=\fakewidth{\frac{2}{5}[v_3(8)+v_3(2)]}
                    {\frac{2}{5}[v_3(2)+v_3(0.50)]} 
                    &&= 1.20,\\   
  v_2(1)&=\fakewidth{\frac{2}{5}[v_3(2)+v_3(0.50)]}
                    {\frac{2}{5}[v_3(2)+v_3(0.50)]}
                    &&= \fakewidth{3.}{1.20}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

then you'll get

[image]

Comment: @Mico: Oops, yes; I just corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be more complicated than suitable for the align environments. You can use generic `array` here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[%
\begin{array}{r@{\,}l@{\,}c@{\,}l@{\,}l}
A&=&BBB&=&CC\\
A&=&B&=&CCCC
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```