# Centering column in alignat environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

How do I center the contents of each cell in the middle column? I am approximating it with `\phantom`, but there's got to be a better way.

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
  &E&\quad&\mathrm{par}&&\quad\Sigma,\\
  &\Psi&\quad&\phantom{p}\mathrm{"}\phantom{r}&&\quad\frac{\epsilon V}{1+4\pi\epsilon F},\\
  &\Psi&\quad&\phantom{p}\mathrm{"}\phantom{r}&&\quad\frac{(1+4\pi\epsilon F)^2}{\epsilon}.
\end{alignat*}
```

thanks

Comment: Why don't you use an `array` or even `tabular`?

Comment: and what is up with those `\mathrm{''}`'s?

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102816/centering-equations-within-alignat-command  ?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At its heart the `alignat` environment is built on TeX's `\halign`.  In that environment you can ignore the formatting specifications for a given column by issuing `\omit`.  Thus writing

```
\omit\hfill text \hfill
```

will give you a centered column of text, since the column specification not only included the left/right alignment but also that the meterial is set as mathematics.  It is probably best to  create a separate command to provide this construction, which may then be used anywhere in an `alignat`, `align` or similar enviroment, at the beginning of a cell:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ditto}{{''}}
\newcommand{\ccol}[1]{\omit\hfill #1\hfill}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  &E&\quad&\ccol{par}&\quad&\Sigma,\\
  &\Psi&&\ccol{\ditto}&&\frac{\epsilon V}{1+4\pi\epsilon F},\\
  &\Psi&&\ccol{\ditto}&&\frac{(1+4\pi\epsilon F)^2}{\epsilon}.
\end{alignat*}

\begin{align}
  E &= mc^2\\
  F &\ccol{is another quantity}\\
  G &= u^2 + v^2 - w^2 + x^2 - y^2 + z^2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Sould you wish to span multiple columns the relevant command is `\multispan`, e.g. `\multispan{3}\hfill text \hfill` will place text spread over three columns and centered.

Alternatively, as Harish Kumar suggests you can use `array` or `tabular`:

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ditto}{{''}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{r@{\quad}c@{\quad}l}
  E&\mathrm{par}&\Sigma,\\
  \Psi&\mathrm{\ditto}&\displaystyle\frac{\epsilon V}{1+4\pi\epsilon F},\\
  \Psi&\mathrm{\ditto}&\displaystyle\frac{(1+4\pi\epsilon F)^2}{\epsilon}.
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{r@{\quad}c@{\quad}l}
    \( E \)&par&\( \Sigma, \)\\
    \( \Psi \)&\ditto&\( \displaystyle\frac{\epsilon V}{1+4\pi\epsilon F}, \)\\
    \( \Psi \)&\ditto&\( \displaystyle\frac{(1+4\pi\epsilon F)^2}{\epsilon}. \)
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

However, the default line spacing from `alignat` is better and you don't need to worry about adjusting the math styles.

Comment: According to my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267543/missing-equation-number-using-omit), using this command with alignat breaks numbering.

Comment: The problem arises when multiple `\ccol`s are used on one line. https://www.overleaf.com/read/mvryrbzzgmkw

Comment: Indeed - it breaks if it is applied to an entry that is not the widest in its column.  egreg's answer to your other question address that issue well.