# Numbering and aligning an equation with multiple columns

Tags: equations, numbering, align, arrays, alignat

I search a way to align an equation with multiple columns where the following criteria should be met:

- The equation tag should be in the last line
- The equal signs should be centered and aligned

Using `alignat` gives me the right numbering but I have been unable to center 
the last equal sign in the second row as it is `overset` with a reference.
Using `array` inside an `equation` I can get the alignment correct (although with more space between the columns) but the numbering is now centered and not at the end.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand\theequation{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}


\begin{document}
\chapter{}
\section{Section}
\subsection{subsection}
\begin{equation}
 1 + 1 = 2 
 \label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

\begin{alignat}{3}
 E =& n^\mu n^\nu T_{\mu\nu} &&=&& \rho \notag \\
 T =& T^\mu_\mu = -\rho + p_r + 2 p_\perp 
                   &&\overset{(\ref{eq:1})}{=}&& 2 (p_\perp -\rho) \notag \\
 S =& T+E &&=&& 2 p_\perp - \rho \notag \\
 p^\mu =& - \gamma^{\mu \alpha} n^\beta T_{\alpha \beta} &&=&& 0 \quad .
\end{alignat}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cclcl}
 E &=& n^\mu n^\nu T_{\mu\nu} &=& \rho  \\
 T &=& T^\mu_\mu = -\rho + p_r + 2 p_\perp 
                   &\overset{(\ref{eq:1})}{=}& 2 (p_\perp -\rho)  \\
 S &=& T+E &= & 2 p_\perp - \rho  \\
 p^\mu &=& - \gamma^{\mu \alpha} n^\beta T_{\alpha \beta} &= & 0 \quad .
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136374/15925 may be adapted to introduce a command `\cmdcol` for material to be centered in a column in display math in `alignat` and related environments:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cmdcol}[1]{\omit\hfil\strut@ \( \m@th\displaystyle #1 \)\hfil}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{equation}
 1 + 1 = 2 
 \label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

\begin{alignat}{2}
 E &= n^\mu n^\nu T_{\mu\nu} &\cmdcol{=}& \rho \notag \\
 T &= T^\mu_\mu = -\rho + p_r + 2 p_\perp 
                   &\cmdcol{\overset{\eqref{eq:1}}{=}}& 2 (p_\perp -\rho) \notag \\
 S &= T+E &\cmdcol{=}& 2 p_\perp - \rho \notag \\
 p^\mu &= - \gamma^{\mu \alpha} n^\beta T_{\alpha \beta} &\cmdcol{=}& 0 \quad .
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

The structure of the `\cmdcol` command is built up to mimic the standard `ams` definition for columns in `align` and friends.

By the way, your numbering scheme is better effected by `\numberwithin`.  I have switch to `mathtools` rather than `amsmath` for the further extensions provided by that package, it loads `amsmath` anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea with `array` is good, but needs some refinement. However, I wouldn't set the equation number above the equals sign, but on the side. I'll show both ways.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\displaystyle{}}c<{{}}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l}

\renewcommand\theequation{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\section{Section}
\subsection{subsection}
\begin{equation}
 1 + 1 = 2 
 \label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}[b]{RCLCL}
 E &=& n^\mu n^\nu T_{\mu\nu} &=& \rho,  \\
 T &=& T^\mu_\mu = -\rho + p_r + 2 p_\perp 
                   &\overset{(\ref{eq:1})}{=}& 2 (p_\perp -\rho),  \\
 S &=& T+E &= & 2 p_\perp - \rho,  \\
 p^\mu &=& - \gamma^{\mu \alpha} n^\beta T_{\alpha \beta} &= & 0.
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}[b]{3}
 E     &= n^\mu n^\nu T_{\mu\nu}                        &&= \rho, \\
 T     &= T^\mu_\mu = -\rho + p_r + 2 p_\perp           &&= 2 (p_\perp -\rho),
   &&\quad\text{by \eqref{eq:1}} \\
 S     &= T+E                                           &&= 2 p_\perp - \rho,  \\
 p^\mu &= -\gamma^{\mu \alpha} n^\beta T_{\alpha \beta} &&= 0.
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]