# Centering a column in align or alignat with desired spacing

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, alignat

Initially, I had the code

```
\begin{align*}
|a_d|_p & = 1 \\
|a_i|_p & \leq 1
\end{align*}
```

which produced the result below:

[image: first image]

This is undesirable because the  vertical bars `|` on the left don't line up. Then I discovered the alignat environment, and tried the code

```
\begin{alignat}{3}
| & a_d & |_p & & & = 1 \\
| & a_i & |_p & & & \leq 1
\end{alignat}
```

which produced the result below:

[image: second image]

This is better, but it's still not great because now the `a_d` and `a_i` don't line up. Ideally, I'd want just the column with the `a_d` and `a_i` to be centered. Then, I looked at the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136366/centering-column-in-alignat-environment), and tried the code

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
| & \omit\hfill $a_d$ \hfill & |_p & & & = 1 \\
| & \omit\hfill $a_i$ \hfill & |_p & & & \leq 1
\end{alignat*}
```

which produced the result below:

[image: third image]

This is better in some respects because each of the vertical bars line up, as do the `a_d` and `a_i`, but now the right-hand vertical bars `|_p` are spaced too far to the right. Any suggestions?

---

UPDATE: After reading the code in Bernard's suggestions, along with some information about `\makemathbox` (from `mathtools`), `\newlength`, and `\settowidth`, I came up with the following code, which seems to do what I want. However, am I doing anything that is deprecated?

```
\newlength{\myl}
\settowidth{\myl}{$a_d$}

\begin{align*}
|a_d|_p & = 1 \\
| \mathmakebox[\myl]{a_i} |_p & \leq 1
\end{align*}
```

Comment: an experienced math copyeditor wouldn't find the original presentation inappropriate.  i think this is a case of "trying too hard".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions, using `mathtools`, and `makebox` for one of them. For the second one , with `eqparbox` , more automated. I define a `\varpabs`  command which uses a tag: all `\varpabs` which share the same tag will have the same width – that of the widest argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{makebox, eqparbox}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP{\pabs}[1]{}\lvert \rvert{_p}{\ifblank{#1}{\:\cdot\:}{#1}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP{\varpabs}[2]{}\lvert\rvert{_p}{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \pabs{a_d} & = 1 \\
  \pabs{\makebox*{$ a_d $}{$ a_i $}} & \leq 1
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \varpabs{A}{a_d + c} & = 1 \\
  \varpabs*{A}{ \frac{a_i }{b_i}} & \leq 1
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also, how does the code I just added to the bottom of my question look?

Comment: @justin You should read barbara's comment on your question: she knows whereof she speaks. (At least, if *anybody* here knows, she does. Conversely, if she doesn't know, we're all whistling in the dark.)

Comment: @cfr I appreciate it... I saw her comment, and while it's reassuring to know I could have left everything as is, I'm also curious about how I can manipulate LaTeX spacing in general, so that's why I'm spending energy on this. Working on this particular task is kind of an instructive example for me.