# Missing equation number using \omit

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations, numbering, lyx

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136374/87160) I found a very useful approach to easily center certain elements in a `alignat` environment using a new command:

```
\newcommand{\ccol}[1]{\omit\hfill $#1$\hfill}
```

I inserted the `$`’s because `\omit` seems to terminate math mode.

```
\begin{alignat}{3}
x_{n}-\frac{f\left(x_{n}\right)}{f^{\prime}\left(x_{n}\right)}-x^{\ast}=\mbox{} & x_{n+1}-x^{\ast} & \mbox{}=\mbox{} & \left(x_{n}-x^{\ast}\right)^{2} & \mbox{}\cdot\frac{f^{\prime\prime}\left(\xi\right)}{2\cdot f^{\prime}\left(x_{n}\right)}\\
& \ccol{\epsilon_{n+1}} & \mbox{}=\mbox{} & \ccol{\epsilon_{n}^{2}} & \mbox{}\cdot\frac{f^{\prime\prime}\left(\xi\right)}{2\cdot f^{\prime}\left(x_{n}\right)}
\end{alignat}
```

[image: result]

Unfortunately, the numbering of the second equation is gone. Even using another command to manually activate numbering for certain equations in `alignat*` results in the above:

```
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}
```

---

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
x_{n}-\frac{f\left(x_{n}\right)}{f^{\prime}\left(x_{n}\right)}-x^{\ast}=\mbox{} & x_{n+1}-x^{\ast} & \mbox{}=\mbox{} & \left(x_{n}-x^{\ast}\right)^{2} & \mbox{}\cdot\frac{f^{\prime\prime}\left(\xi\right)}{2\cdot f^{\prime}\left(x_{n}\right)}\numberthis\\
 & \ccol{\epsilon_{n+1}} & \mbox{}=\mbox{} & \ccol{\epsilon_{n}^{2}} & \mbox{}\cdot\frac{f^{\prime\prime}\left(\xi\right)}{2\cdot f^{\prime}\left(x_{n}\right)}\numberthis
\end{alignat*}
```

How to not omit numbering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing `\omit` breaks the typesetting of the equation number, as you discovered.

I suggest my macro `\Cen` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209732/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Cen}[2]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
    #2%
  \else
    \makebox[\ifcase\expandafter #1\maxcolumn@widths\fi]{$\displaystyle#2$}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{n})}{f'(x_{n})}-x^* = {} & x_{n+1}-x^* & {}={} & (x_{n}-x^*)^{2} &
  {}\cdot\frac{f''(\xi)}{2\cdot f'(x_{n})}\\
& \Cen{2}{\epsilon_{n+1}} & {}={} & \Cen{4}{\epsilon_{n}^{2}} &
  {}\cdot\frac{f''(\xi)}{2\cdot f'(x_{n})}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

You just have to tell what column you're in.

Note that I simplified the input removing all the unnecessary `\left` and `\right` and also using `'` instead of `^{\prime}`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the code formatting, I used LyX to generate it.

Comment: @ominug What worries me is the wealth of useless (and harming) `\left` and `\right`. Developers of LyX should read this site and the uncountable times we say “don't abuse `\left` and `\right`”.

Comment: @ominug Are you sure LyX put in `\left`? If you put in `(`, I don't believe LyX will change it. If you add "smart" parentheses (e.g. through delimiters dialog) then yes the `left` is added.

Comment: Yes, because it’s just a key combination of “Alt + M, (” in LyX and then missing parentheses are no problem anymore. But you are able to insert single (’s also.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way that doesn't interfere with the numbering is to set the contents you want to centre in a box of pre-specified width, or calculate the width using `\widthof` (from [`calc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc)).

Below I've used [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) (which loads [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) and `calc`) to make a math box using `\mathmakebox` of width equal to `\widthof{...}` of the element above it in the construction:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
  x_n - \frac{f\bigl(x_n\bigr)}{f'\bigl(x_n\bigr)} - x^\ast 
    &= x_{n+1} - x^\ast 
    &= \bigl(x_n - x^\ast\bigr)^2
      &\cdot \frac{f''\bigl(\xi\bigr)}{2 \cdot f'\bigl(x_n\bigr)} \\
  &\phantom{{}={}} \mathmakebox[\widthof{$x_{n+1} - x^\ast$}]{\epsilon_{n+1}} 
    &= \mathmakebox[\widthof{$\bigl(x_n - x^\ast\bigr)^2$}]{\epsilon_{n}^{2}}
      &\cdot \frac{f''\bigl(\xi\bigr)}{2 \cdot f'\bigl(x_n\bigr)}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```