# Centering column in matrix equations

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, matrices

I'm looking for a way to centre-align the centre column (**\xrightarrow**s) in this construction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}[2]
    \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        2 & 2 & \vline & 3 \\
        1 & -3 & \vline & 2
    \end{bmatrix*} & \xrightarrow{-R_2 \to R_1} && \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        1 & 5 & \vline & 1 \\
        1 & -3 & \vline & 2
    \end{bmatrix*} \\
    \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        1 & 5 & \vline & 1 \\
        1 & -3 & \vline & 2
    \end{bmatrix*} & \xrightarrow{3 R_1} && \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        3 & 15 & \vline & \mathllap{-}1 \\
        1 & -3 & \vline & 2
    \end{bmatrix*}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Previous answers I've seen have used:

- an **array** environment to align columns ([Centering equations within alignat command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102816/centering-equations-within-alignat-command)), but in this case the rows become too close together and can't be separated by adjusting the spacing of array rows because this also affects the matrix environments.
- an **alignat** environment ([Centering column in alignat environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136366/centering-column-in-alignat-environment)) but this makes the centered column a text environment. I need a math environment.

Comment: is insetead of `\end{bmatrix*} & \xrightarrow{-R_2 \to R_1} && \begin{bmatrix*}[r]` acepptable to you `\end{bmatrix*} & \xrightarrow{-R_2 \to R_1}  \begin{bmatrix*}[r]`?

Comment: No, I want the **\xrightarrow**s to be centre-aligned, not left-aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alignat` environment works just fine here. What made you believe it turns the centre column in textmode? Note the starred versions of the matrix environmùents require `mathtools`. I took the opportunity to align the right brackets of the righmots matrices, using the `\mathllap` command defined by this package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        2 & 2 & \vline & 3 \\
        1 & -3 & \vline & 2
    \end{bmatrix*} & \xrightarrow{-R_2 \to R_1} && \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        1 & 5 & \vline & 1 \\
        1 & -3 & \vline & 2
    \end{bmatrix*} \\[1ex]
    \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        1 & 5 & \vline & 1 \\
        1 & -3 & \vline & 2
    \end{bmatrix*} & \xrightarrow{-R_2 \to R_1} && \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        0 & 8 & \vline & \mathllap{-}1 \\
        1 & -3 & \vline & 2
    \end{bmatrix*}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To centre  the `\rightarrow`s in their column, we can use  the `eqparbox` package. I defines a `\eqmathbox` command, which types its contents in math mode and uss a system of tags. All boxes sharing the same tag have the width of the wides of their contents, which is centred in its box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        2 & 2 & \vline & 3 \\
        1 & -3 & \vline & 2
    \end{bmatrix*} & \eqmathbox{\xrightarrow{-R₂ + R_1\to R₁}} && \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        1 & 5 & \vline & 1 \\
        1 & -3 & \vline & 2
    \end{bmatrix*} \\[1ex]
    \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        1 & 5 & \vline & 1 \\
        1 & -3 & \vline & 2
    \end{bmatrix*} & \eqmathbox{\xrightarrow{-R₂ \to R₁}} && \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        0 & 8 & \vline & \mathllap{-}1 \\
        1 & -3 & \vline & 2
    \end{bmatrix*}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't say that the **alignat** environment turns the centre column into text mode, but the referenced answer **does** turn it into text mode. In your answer the **\xrightarrow** column is left-aligned, not centred. I suspect my example doesn't show this clearly, I'll edit it.

Comment: @user164587: I se what you mean: the `\xrightarrow`s look centred because they have the same width. I have a solution with `eqparbox` . Please take a look at my updated answer.