# Centering between alignment characters

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, alignment

Using the standard "align"-command, I cannot find a way to center equations between alignment characters. Is there a different environment which is better suited for this problem?
My problem is as follows

```
\begin{align}
  a &=& \underbrace{\text{insert long equation here}} &=& \text{something}\\
    &=& b &=& \text{something}
\end{align}
```

where now the b would be displayed leftbound on the equals sign. I would like if it was displayed centered between the 2 equal signs, preferably right below the underbrace. I know that I can also add it to the underbrace, but that is not what I'm looking or.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136366/15925 helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `eqparbox`; the first argument is an arbitrary label (which should be unique per usage).

Better use `alignat`, for this display. In any case, `&=&` is incorrect with `align` and the other `amsmath` environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand{\matheqbox}[2]{\eqmakebox[#1][c]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  a &= \matheqbox{A}{\underbrace{\text{insert long equation here}}} &&= \text{something}\\
    &= \matheqbox{A}{b}                                             &&= \text{something}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can your elaborate, why using     &=& is incorrect with align? I know that "it works" is not a good reason for it to be correct, but it has worked for me quite well so far and I don't see any problems.

Comment: @Sellerie Did you notice how big is the space after `=` in the `&=&` case?

Comment: No, I didn't, but I guess you are right. Working with only one alignment-character appears to be better suited. Thanks so far.
Also thank you for showing me the alignat-command, which might be much more suited in many equations.