# alignat: Centering, multicolumn

Tags: equations, arrays, alignat, tags

How can I center all columns in a multicolumn, multiline equation?

1. The `array` environment:

   - Does not allow for multiple float numbers.
   - Does incorporate space between columns.
   - Does allow centering between columns.
   - Does allow use of multicolumn.
2. The `alignat` environment:

   - Does allow for multiple float numbers.
   - Does not incorporate space between columns.
   - Does not allow centered columns.
   - Does not allow use of multicolumn.

The `array` environment already looks perfect.
Is it possible to `\tag` each line of `array` with an incremented equation number?

Else,
Is it possible to center and space columns in `alignat`?
Also, how can multicolumn be used in `alignat`?

All columns must have scope across all equations,
so using separate `array` environments is not enough.

**MWE**:

`alignat`: 0.1, 0.2
`array`: 0.3

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{11}
\newcommand*\centermathcell[1]{\omit\hfil$\displaystyle#1$\hfil\ignorespaces}
%\begin{array}{7}
%\centermathcell{
K_{\ddot{\phi}}
%}
& \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
\ddot{\phi}_{x}\\
\ddot{\phi}_{y}\\
\end{bmatrix}
& + &
K_{\dot{\phi}} 
& \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{\phi}_{x}\\
\dot{\phi}_{y}\\
\end{bmatrix}
& + &
K_{\phi}
& \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{x}\\
\phi_{y}\\
\end{bmatrix}
& = &
K_{v}
& \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{mtr.l}\\
v_{mtr.r}\\
\end{bmatrix}
%%
\\[+2em]
%%
I
& \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\ddot{\phi}_{x}\\
\ddot{\phi}_{y}\\
\end{bmatrix}
& = &
-K_{\ddot{\phi}}^{-1}
\cdot 
K_{\dot{\phi}} 
& \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{\phi}_{x}\\
\dot{\phi}_{y}\\
\end{bmatrix}
& + &
-K_{\ddot{\phi}}^{-1}
\cdot 
K_{\phi}
& \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{x}\\
\phi_{y}\\
\end{bmatrix}
& + &
K_{\ddot{\phi}}^{-1}
\cdot 
K_{v}
& \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{mtr.l}\\
v_{mtr.r}\\
\end{bmatrix}
%\end{array}
%%
\end{alignat}




\vspace{+4em}




\begin{gather}
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
K_{\ddot{\phi}}
& \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
\ddot{\phi}_{x}\\
\ddot{\phi}_{y}\\
\end{bmatrix}
& + &
K_{\dot{\phi}} 
& \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{\phi}_{x}\\
\dot{\phi}_{y}\\
\end{bmatrix}
& + &
K_{\phi}
& \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{x}\\
\phi_{y}\\
\end{bmatrix}
& = &
K_{v}
& \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{mtr.l}\\
v_{mtr.r}\\
\end{bmatrix}
%%
\\[+2em]
%%
I
& \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\ddot{\phi}_{x}\\
\ddot{\phi}_{y}\\
\end{bmatrix}
& = &
-K_{\ddot{\phi}}^{-1}
\cdot 
K_{\dot{\phi}} 
& \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{\phi}_{x}\\
\dot{\phi}_{y}\\
\end{bmatrix}
& + &
-K_{\ddot{\phi}}^{-1}
\cdot 
K_{\phi}
& \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{x}\\
\phi_{y}\\
\end{bmatrix}
& + &
K_{\ddot{\phi}}^{-1}
\cdot 
K_{v}
& \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{mtr.l}\\
v_{mtr.r}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{array}
%%
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

**Notes**:

This question is a continuation of [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380909/robust-equation-numbering/380928?noredirect=1#comment943456_380928),
and was not solved by [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102816/centering-equations-within-alignat-command).

Comment: Are you sure of the  `+–` in the second row? Maybe you meant `±`?

Comment: @Bernard It looked different when the `array` environment was in place, guaranteeing all `+` and `=`, with `-` as part of the coefficient and actual space between the indices.

Comment: @Bernard Improved MWE.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `equationarray` environment from the package [`eqnarray`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eqnarray).

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqnarray}

\begin{document}

\bgroup\arraycolsep 0.1em
\begin{equationarray}{*{11}{c}}
  K_{\ddot{\phi}} & \cdot
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \ddot{\phi}_{x}\\
    \ddot{\phi}_{y}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
  & + & K_{\dot{\phi}} & \cdot
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{\phi}_{x}\\
    \dot{\phi}_{y}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
  & + & K_{\phi} & \cdot
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \phi_{x}\\
    \phi_{y}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
  & = & K_{v} & \cdot
  \begin{bmatrix}
    v_{\mathrm{mtr.l}}\\
    v_{\mathrm{mtr.r}}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \\[2em]
  I & \cdot
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \ddot{\phi}_{x}\\
    \ddot{\phi}_{y}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
  & = & -K_{\ddot{\phi}}^{-1} \cdot K_{\dot{\phi}} & \cdot
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{\phi}_{x}\\
    \dot{\phi}_{y}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
  & + & -K_{\ddot{\phi}}^{-1} \cdot K_{\phi} & \cdot
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \phi_{x}\\
    \phi_{y}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
  & + & K_{\ddot{\phi}}^{-1} \cdot K_{v} & \cdot
  \begin{bmatrix}
    v_{\mathrm{mtr.l}}\\
    v_{\mathrm{mtr.r}}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equationarray}
\egroup

\end{document}
```

This environment also supports `multicolumn`:

[image: Multicolumn example]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqnarray}

\begin{document}

\arraycolsep .16667em   %\thinspace
\begin{equationarray}{rcl@{\quad}rcl}
  x&=&y &u&=&v \\
  \multicolumn{3}{c@{\quad}}{xyz}&p&=&q
\end{equationarray}

\end{document}
```