# Centering alignments in equations

Tags: equations, align, arrays, center

I have a very long set of equations that I put in an array. They must be aligned as

```
\begin{array}{lclc}
 A     & Long expression              &  \text{\hspace{.5cm}}   & Long expression \\
.
.
.
Z  & Long expression              &  \text{\hspace{.5cm}}   & Long expression \\
\end{array}
```

This is for give you an idea of how long the expression can be. Moreover the second and fourth component must be centered.
I would like to use align because it allows for page breaks of the equations in case they are too long, but if I use them, then the second and fourth components of the align are not centered anymore.
How can I have a structure as follows:

```
\begin{align}
 A     & Long centered expression              &  \text{\hspace{.5cm}}   & Long centered expression \\
.
.
.
Z  & Long centered expression              &  \text{\hspace{.5cm}}   & Long centered expression \\
\end{align}
```

I need the equations to be numbered, centered and with the possibility of breaking in multiple pages if they are too long.

**EDIT**

I add an example:

```
\[
\begin{array}{lclc}
 A     & This is a very long expression              &  \text{\hspace{.5cm}}   & Also this is a long expression \\
 B     & Normal             &  \text{\hspace{.5cm}}   & Something \\
Z  & Short              &  \text{\hspace{.5cm}}   & This is even longer expression of before \\
\end{array}
\]
```

If you try it on a TeX file the second and the fourth columns are centered with respect to their content. If I have a very long expression, then if I use array, it is possible that the equations do not fit well in the page because it cannot be broken in multiple pages. So I was thinking of using align with \allowpagebreaks[1]. But if I use

```
\[
\begin{align}
 A     & This is a very long expression              &  \text{\hspace{.5cm}}   & Also this is a long expression \\
 B     & Normal             &  \text{\hspace{.5cm}}   & Something \\
Z  & Short              &  \text{\hspace{.5cm}}   & This is even longer expression of before \\
\end{align}
\]
```

You see that the alignments of the second and fourth columns are with respect to the & symbol, and not centered with respect to their content.

I hope that the example clarifies my question

Comment: it will be much easier for people to understand the issue and test answers if you supplied a small but complete test document.  alignments are right and left aligned to the alignment point so a&=b  so effectively they are centred if you can structure it that way

Comment: I added something one can copy and past in a TeX document and see what I mean.

Comment: well a complete document would be easier especially if it had more representative example, also `align`  should not be in `\[`  if I cut and paste your fragment into a document I get `! Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;`

Comment: I found this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102845/167169 that actually does what I'm asking with alignat. It's lenghty because I need to put the command at each line, but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: glad you found something that does what you need. I marked the question as duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can not have `align` inside `\[` The simplest and most common way is to add alignment points within the expression so they alig towards the alignment point rather tahn appear to be flush left or right. I added | here to make the alignment visible in teh output but that is not needed. Note that the example text is already too wide to fit in a standard text block even if I remove the .5cm spacing (there is no need for `\hspace` to be inside `\text`)  If you have a much wider text block or your real expressions are smaller you could of course re-add spacing, although `align` already adds space between each expression (that is between each pair of columns)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{align}
 A     && This isa very&|long expression      & Also this &|is a long expression \\
 B     &&  Normal&|              & Some&|thing \\
Z  &&       Short&|              & This is even &|longer expression of before
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `alignat` and `eqparbox`. The label for the boxes is automatically generated for each `align-lcc` display.

***Dont'*** add a trailing `\\`, as is mandatory for `align` and friends.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{align-lcc}{b}
 {
  \mininno_align_lcc:n { #1 }
 }
 {}

\seq_new:N \l__mininno_align_body_seq
\seq_new:N \l__mininno_align_row_seq
\tl_new:N \l__mininno_align_body_tl
\int_new:N \g__mininno_align_rows_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mininno_align_lcc:n
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g__mininno_align_rows_int
  \tl_clear:N \l__mininno_align_body_tl
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__mininno_align_body_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l__mininno_align_body_seq \__mininno_align_row:nn
  \begin{alignat}{3}
  \tl_use:N \l__mininno_align_body_tl
  \end{alignat}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mininno_align_row:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__mininno_align_row_seq { & } { #2 }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l__mininno_align_body_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l__mininno_align_row_seq { 1 } }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l__mininno_align_body_tl
   {
    \__mininno_align_cell:nn {A}{\seq_item:Nn \l__mininno_align_row_seq { 2 }}
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l__mininno_align_body_tl
   {
    \__mininno_align_cell:nn {B}{\seq_item:Nn \l__mininno_align_row_seq { 3 }}
   }
  \int_compare:nF { #1 == \seq_count:N \l__mininno_align_body_seq }
   { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mininno_align_body_tl { \\ } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mininno_align_cell:nn
 {
  &\quad&
  \eqmakebox[#1-\int_to_arabic:n {\g__mininno_align_rows_int}][c]{$\displaystyle#2$}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{align-lcc}
 A & This is a very long expression & Also this is a long expression \\
 B & Normal                         & Something \\
 Z & Short                          & This is even longer expression of before
\end{align-lcc}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to split the input at `\\`, then each row at `&` and fill in using `\eqmakebox`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I copied your tex but it does not work. Something that I'm missing?

Comment: @AlessandroMininno Try adding `\usepackage{xparse}` (but you should also update your TeX system).

Comment: I was using Overleaf, so it should be update. In any case, I found this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102845/167169 that does what I'm asking but on every line I need to add the command. Is there a way to make it automatic?